# Views query alter add orderby function FIELD()

Tags: views, 8, database

I can't figure out how to add following expression to the views query:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(field_dataid,3,2,1,4)
```

QueryPluginBase only gives the option to add:

```
$query->addOrderBy('node_field_data', 'nid', ASC);
```

But doesn't give the option to add an expression.

The Sql interface has the options to add an expression:

```
  $query->addExpression('FIELD(node_field_data.nid,3,2,1,4)', 'order_field');
  $query->orderBy('order_field', 'ASC');
```

But this doesn't work with the views query object.

So how can i add orderby expression to the views query object?

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar answer here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/200662/79998

You should either use `$query->addField()` to add the expression and then append or unshift in `$query->orderby` array,
or you can use directly `$query->addOrderBy()` to add the expression and order, if it's ok to be added last.

```
$query->addOrderBy(NULL, 'FIELD(node_field_data.nid,3,2,1,4)', 'ASC', 'order_field');
```