# How to sort view using already sorted array in hook_views_query_alter

Tags: views, 8

I have the following code to alter a view and filter IN only specific nodes

```
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if($view->id() == 'myview'){
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        if ($condition['field'] == "node_field_data.nid") {
          $condition = array(
            'field' => "node_field_data.nid",
            'value' => [2,4,6,1,3,5],
            'operator' => 'in',
          );
          break;
        }
      }
    } 
    //this does not work    
    //$query->addOrderBy('node_field_data','nid', 'ASC', '', [2,4,6,1,3,5]);    
  }
}
```

and I want to sort them with this specific order `[2,4,6,1,3,5]`

I tried not putting any sorting field but the view sorts the nodes by created date.  How can I tell the view to sort them in this manner ?

I think I need to use `ORDER BY FIELD('node_field_data'.'nid','2','4','6','1','3','5')` in sql but I don't know how its done in drupal

I have seen [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189303/how-to-sort-on-different-columns-in-the-same-view/200662#200662) but don't know how it applies to my case

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out

```
$query->addOrderBy(NULL, 'FIELD(node_field_data.nid,2,4,6,1,3,5)', 'ASC', 'order_field');
```

Comment: What is `'order_field'` here? already `node_field_data.nid` has been specified in `FIELD`. What should I give in `'order_field'`?

Comment: @siddiq order_field is an (optional) alias - for me, it was necessary because my $field is a formula. I also found it necessary to remove all sort criteria under the View's UI for it to work.

Comment: @GiorgosK - this everytime creates an error for me saying column name not found. Is this something that you came across ?

Comment: @AkiShankar sorry have not seen anything and this code is still running where it was deployed